# Continuity test buzzer sounding continuously

Tags: digital-logic, multimeter

I have a  digital multimeter (DT 9205) which went on the blink recently. I was using the continuity function to check a circuit. With the wisdom of hindsight, I think it is possible that the cicuit might have been “live”, although none of the two fuses of the DMM blew.  In any case after the test, the buzzer sounds continuously & the LED comes on as soon as I switch the instrument on. The other functions however, still appear to be working as usual.

I shall appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction for where to look for the fault.

Comment: Just a wild stab but there are a couple of back to back protection diodes in circuit - could be one or both have been fused

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you don't have or can't find a schematic for it (if you do let us know) so:

First thing is to open it up and take a look around the input circuitry, something blown/shorted may be easy to spot visibly (as Jim mentions any protection components are a good bet)
If the rest of the functions are still working, it may be just the continuity circuit which is damaged - if this is the only function which requires the buzzer on the meter, tracing back from the buzzer to any driving circuitry may prove helpful.